# first-child in jQuery doesn't seem to be finding the right element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm using this jQuery code

```
$('div:first-child').text('change me');
```

And this HTML in the body section:

```
<div class="myclass">
<strong>test1</strong>
<p>test2</p>
<strong>test3</strong>
<p>test4</p>
</div>
```

I thought this would just replace "test1", but it seems to replace everything such that all I see on the page is "change me".

Have I misunderstood what first-child does (I assumed this jQuery code would replace the first child element, which is the test1 of strong, of the first div it finds)? Or is my code wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `:first-child` selects the first element of a list of elements. So `div:first-child` will be the first div found. While `'div :first-child'` with a space (!) will address all elements in that div and selects the first out of them.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. As a follow up question, if I have two div's (so imagine that code above copied twice), then you code (with the space!) would replace the first element in both divs. What would I need to do, just to replace the first child of the first div?

Comment: Give the div's an id and the go with `#divid1 :first-child`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the div element selector then a child selector with the :first-child selector

```
$('div > :first-child').text('change me');
```

Your code is searching for a `div` element which is the first child of its parent element, instead of finding the first child within the div element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tzKCY/)

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. Try this:

```
$('div strong:first-child').text('change me');
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hG9sd/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If it selects all elements that are the first child of their parent (the div?), then wouldn't I see "change me" 4 times instead of 1?

Comment: Good question. :first-child will only give you the first element within the parent element. The other elements within your div are the 2nd, 3rd and 4th children, respectively.